# Android - Error loading local js in application

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, webview

I have an application which is basically a webview app. The website is based on angular js. Problem is the website takes a lot of time to start rendering. So I tried loading js from the asset folder. I used WebResourceResponse in my webviewclient

```
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

        if(url.startsWith("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.min.js")){
            return loadFromAssets(url, "angular.min.js", "application/javascript", "");
                               }
    return null;
    }

private WebResourceResponse loadFromAssets( String url,
                                            String assetPath, String mimeType, String encoding){

    AssetManager assetManager = this.activity.getAssets();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Loading from assets: " + assetPath);

        input = assetManager.open("/" + assetPath);
        WebResourceResponse response =
                new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, input);

        return response;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("WEB-APP", "Error loading " + assetPath + " from assets: " +
                e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I keep getting the filenotfound exception

```
    07-26 17:19:21.662  20883-21536/com.exun.brinjal D/﹕ Loading from assets: angular.min.js
07-26 17:19:21.663  20883-21536/com.exun.brinjal E/WEB-APP﹕ Error loading angular.min.js from assets: /angular.min.js
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /angular.min.js
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:335)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:309)
            at com.exun.brinjal.HelloWebViewClient.loadFromAssets(HelloWebViewClient.java:85)
            at com.exun.brinjal.HelloWebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(HelloWebViewClient.java:37)
            at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldInterceptRequest(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:283)
            at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents$IoThreadClientImpl.shouldInterceptRequest(AwContents.java:244)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-26 17:19:21.666  20883-21536/com.exun.brinjal D/﹕ Loading from assets: angular-route.min.js
07-26 17:19:21.669  20883-21536/com.exun.brinjal E/WEB-APP﹕ Error loading angular-route.min.js from assets: /angular-route.min.js
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /angular-route.min.js
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:335)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:309)
            at com.exun.brinjal.HelloWebViewClient.loadFromAssets(HelloWebViewClient.java:85)
            at com.exun.brinjal.HelloWebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(HelloWebViewClient.java:40)
            at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldInterceptRequest(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:283)
            at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents$IoThreadClientImpl.shouldInterceptRequest(AwContents.java:244)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I have tried to change `assetManager.open("/" + assetPath);` to file:/// and /assets but it doesn't help. All the js and css files I need are in the assets folder. I also want to know how will I get to load all those files also.

Answer (score 0):

After some brainstorming, the answer was to remove "/" from `assetManager.open("/" + assetPath);`

So finally just put `assetManager.open(assetPath);` in the code and voila!